# index out of range exception occurred

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, visual-studio, c#-4.0

do not be tired
I defined a 1000-element presentation in the Windows application form space and used it in various areas of the program, but unfortunately I encounter the following error. Thank you for your help:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTbQg.png)

I have defined this variable as follows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWzB3.png)

Comment: index is 0 based ... so 1000th element has index 999

Comment: also: asked already, do not post code as images

Comment: Just remove the `=` in `i <= 1000` and you're good

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in arrays start with 0. So array with 1000 elements will have indexes from 0 to 999. It throws at the 1000th index. As a solution, you can change your loop to have following condition: i < 1000 instead.

Comment: I changed the code as follows but I still get the error:
for (int i = 0; i <1000; i ++)
            {
                bloor1 [i] = new TextBox ();
                bloor2 [i] = new TextBox ();
}